# Google charts Area chart, How to avoid the color shades in charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

[Google Area charts**

```js
This is "options" I used in my code.

var options = {
        // title: 'Company Performance',
        // hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
        // vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        vAxis: { 
            format: '#',  
            gridlines: { count: 4},
          },
      };
```

**][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuYXw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following chart option...

```
areaOpacity: 1
```

Comment: By using "areaOpacity: 0", shades are disappered. Thank you